# How tomcat or any server pass the request to the spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, server

I always be told how spring boot work on the coming request, but I really want to know how the spring boot get the request, how the server pass it to the spring boot application.

Answer (score 3):

That needs to have an answer of the size of one book, to cover all the details.

### Very shortly:

Tomcat is a Servlet Engine, a.k.a Servlet Container, a.k.a Web Container/Server, and it *knows*, with the help of Deployment Descriptor (defined in the web.xml or by annotations), how to map particular URL/URIs to particular Servlet instances.

[image]

Spring, or any Java-based Web Framework/Technology, under the hood, uses Servlet.

How Spring builds on top of that, is another book. Please try to research yourself as well.

Comment: And from which book this image from? I tried to find some internals on the topic, but it is rather complex

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot embeds Apache Tomcat which starts when the application registers one or more Spring Controller.
Apache listens on a given port (default 8080) which can be customised, also HTTPS can be enabled, and routes the incoming request to the controllers (according to path configuration).

The controllers perform the necessary logic (business rules, DB access, etc..) and provide a response (for example JSON for services or using a view like a HTML file).

You can customise the Tomcat version or decide to use the embedded Jetty. On production it is normal to deploy a dedicated HTTP server (Apache, NGINX) which is more robust and (often) hardened from a security point of view.